# fail connect to access database with netbeans

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans

I am doing a practical assessment task for my IT class and I am having some trouble with my database connection.

The error is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error unable to open registry key'Temporary(volatile) jet DSN for process 0x858 Thread 0xa20 dbc 0x38825c Jet
```

with the throw, catch it said:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: have you created dsn for your access database

Comment: possible duplicate of ["General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) ..." from Access ODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244425/general-error-unable-to-open-registry-key-temporary-volatile-from-access)